# How to calculate the number of displayed rows in a repeat control

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

In my XPages application I am displaying a list of objects via the xp:repeat control.

I also use the xe:pagerAddRows control to add an X numbers of rows to the repeat control.

In the text of the xe:pagerAddRows control I want to display how many more items there are. Therefor I need to know the number of rows currently displayed in the repeat control.

How must I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this:

```
var text = strings["btn_show_more"]
var dv = getComponent('rptHistory');
return text + " (" + (dv.getRowCount() - dv.getRows()) + ")";
```

More on the add rows control can be read here https://xcellerant.net/2013/08/07/xpages-data-views-5-pager-add-rows-control/